# Schröder–Bernstein theorem in category.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In set theory, Schröder–Bernstein theorem assert for every set $A$ and $B$ if there exists injections from $A$ into $B$, from $B$ into $A$. Then there exists a bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

I want to know does this assertion holds in category?

Let $C$ be a category with terminal object and pull backs. For two objects $A$ and $B$ if there exists injections from $A$ into $B$ and from $B$ into $A$, then there exists an arrow from $A$ into $B$ which is injective and surjective.
If necessary, we assume the well-pointed property for category.

The following is some definitons;

1. An arrow $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective if for every parallel arrow $h_1:1\rightarrow A$ and $h_2:1\rightarrow A$, $fh_1=fh_2$ implies $h_1=h_2$. where $1$ is the terminal object.
2. An arrow $f:A\rightarrow B$ is surjective if for an arrow $y:1\rightarrow B$ there exists some arrow $x:1\rightarrow A$ such that $fx=y$ holds.
3. A category is well-pointed if the terminal object is a separator. An object $S$ is a separator if for any parallel arrows $x,y:A\rightarrow B$ if $x\not= y$, there exists $f:S\rightarrow A$ such that $xf\not= yf$

Comment: Related [math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1058/3959).

Comment: Does "bijective" mean "injective and surjective", or "invertible"?

Comment: Bijective means the function is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This fails in the category of topological spaces.

The terminal object is the one-element space, and it is easy to check that this is a separator, and that being "injective" or "surjective" is the same as being injective or surjective as a function.

But if $A=(0,1)$ and $B=[0,1]$ are an open and a closed interval, then there are continuous injective maps in both directions, but no continuous bijection between the two.

Comment: Just to check: there’s no homeomorphism $f:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ because such a function is necessarily monotonic (by the IVT) and so whatever value $f(0)$ is, (let’s say wlog $f$ is nondecreasing) $f$ will not contain $(0,f(0))\subset(0,1)$ so cannot be a bijection. Is that right? Or is there a more general proof along the lines of: “an open subset cannot be homeomorphic to a nonopen subset of the same topological space”

Comment: @FShrike The OP's definition of "bijection" corresponds to "continuous bijection" in this case, not "homeomorphism". A quick way to see that there is no continuous bijection $[0,1]\to(0,1)$ is that a continuous image of a compact space is compact. But your proof also works, and uses less technology. But it's not true that an open subset cannot be homeomorphic to a nonopen subset of the same space: for example, $[0,2]$ is an open subset of itself, but is homeomorphic to the nonopen subset $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am fairly certain that continuous bijection implies homeomorphism in the real numbers though, no? Or does that theorem really only apply to compact Hausdorff spaces

Comment: @FShrike If by "in the real numbers" you mean "between subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$", then no: the map $f: (0,1)\cup\{2\}\to (0,1]$ given by $f(x)=x$ if $x\in(0,1)$ and $f(2)=1$ is a continuous bijection but not a homeomorphism. But anyway, your proof that there is no homeomorphism $[0,1]\to(0,1)$ also proves the stronger statement that there is no continuous bijection.

Comment: That is a nice counterexample. I think I was confused with the theorem of real analysis which, on reflection, applies to intervals only